# Retrieve info from multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I reached a point of many, many hours trying to figure out, how to retrieve content from an multidimensional array in PHP. I have worked many many hours with multidimensional arrays without any problem, but now I have a new routine which is making me crazy.

This array specifically is a 4 lines/10 columns bidimensional array, like shown below.

```
[
    [
        8038,
        'ClientA',
        'PersonA',
        'Construtor',
        'Ganhador Concurso',
        '2017-09-01',
        'Outro (Não Presencial)',
        'Prospeccao',
        '0',
        ''
    ],
    [
        9232,
        'ClientB',
        'PersonB',
        'Engenharia',
        'Ganhador Concurso',
        '0000-00-00',
        'Outro (Não Presencial)',
        'Prospeccao',
        '0',
        ''
    ],
    [
        9233,
        'ClientC',
        'PersonC',
        'Construtor',
        'Ganhador Concurso',
        '2017-09-01',
        'Outro (Não Presencial)',
        'Prospeccao',
        '0',
        ''
    ],
    [
        8037,
        'ClientD',
        'PersonD',
        'Construtor',
        'Ganhador Concurso',
        '2017-09-01',
        'Outro (Não Presencial)',
        'Prospeccao',
        '0',
        ''
    ]
]
```

The array name is `$matriz_linha3`.

My code to retrieve it:

```
    echo "\n<p><table align=center border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 bordercolor=#FFFFFF width=750>";
    $linha_cab  = "\n<tr align=top>";
    $linha_cab .= "\n<td colspan=10 bgcolor=#FFFF00><center>Entidades da Oportunidade</center></td>";
    $linha_cab .= "\n</tr>";
    echo $linha_cab;
    print_r($matriz_linha3);
    $contador1 = count($matriz_linha3);
    $contador2 = max(array_map('count',$matriz_linha3));
    for($p=0; $p<$contador1 ; $p++) {
       $linha_lks  = "\n<tr align=top>";
       for($q=1; $q<=$contador2 ; $q++) {
          $linha_lks .= "\n<td>$matriz_linha3[$p][$q]</td>";
       }  // fim do ciclo q
      $linha_lks .= "\n</tr>";
      echo $linha_lks;
    } // fim do ciclo p
    echo  "\n</table>";
```

[This is the output(!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONenN.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain what specific content you're trying to get out of it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is with your variable templates in your strings:

```
"\n<td>$matriz_linha3[$p][$q]</td>"
```

The string your created is ment to output the value, that is in the field `$matriz_linha3[$p][$q]`, like the value `Ganhador Concurso` for `$matriz_linha3[0][4]`. The string formatted yet reads only `$matriz_linha3[$p]` as a variable and prints the `[$q]`afterwards, resulting in your output.

To solve this issue, you should use curly brackets in your strings to determine when your variables begin and end:

```
"\n<td>{$matriz_linha3[$p][$q]}</td>"
```

Now PHP knows, that the while string `$matriz_linha3[$p][$q]` is a variable and calculates the value for it.

Since you do not need the indices from the `for` loops i would yet rather suggest to use `foreach` loops.

```
foreach($matriz_linha3 as $row) {
    $linha_lks  = "\n<tr align=top>";
    foreach($row as $column) {
        $linha_lks .= "\n<td>{$column}</td>";
    }
    $linha_lks .= "\n</tr>"
}
```

Like this you neither need the variable `$contador1` nor `$contador2` and your code gets more readable.

Comment: Thank you so much Philipp, I really appreciated your help, being a php autodidact learner for the last 12 years, I have to be honest, I would never discover by myself